# Ground Plane - Video Control when out of camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am creating an AR app for our business before I was just using standard image targets in Unity/Vuforia however for tracking stability I have switched to using Ground Planes.

Within the App, it is looking for an image target and then playing a video. However, using the Ground PLane I need the video to stop when it is not in view and then restart when it is.

Can you help?

Thanks.

Comment: Wait if you are using ground plane why do you have an image target? Ground plane is for detecting planes

Comment: The image target is to be able to identify different 'targets' within the app. Dependent on the target identified it will play a different video

Comment: Well the issue is you are probably using `Extended tracking` since you use ground planes. It means your application will continue tracking those image targets. You can try disabling `Extended Tracking` and play the video is image is tracked.